# Input string was not in the correct format converting string to decimal

Tags: c#

I am pulling a string out my app settings which is in a string format and is set to"0.50M"

```
        Decimal maxLength= 0.50M;
        
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxCallLength"]))
            maxLength= Convert.ToDecimal(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxCallLength"]);
```

How can I convert 0.50M to decimal without getting the input string error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex.

1. Confirm It is a x*million
2. Remove "M"
3. Convert to Decimal
4. Multiply by 10^6 to put it back in the millions.

   ```
    using System;


    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string maxLengthString = "0.50M";
            Regex million = new Regex(@"\A\d+\.\d+\M");
            Regex m = new Regex(@"\M\z");
            if (million.IsMatch(maxLengthString))
            {
                maxLengthString = m.Replace(maxLengthString, "");
                Decimal maxLength = Decimal.Parse(maxLengthString);
                maxLength = maxLength * (Decimal)Math.Pow(10,6);
            }


        }
    }
   ```